# jQuery load external swf into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, flash

Hi I have an html page with jQuery accordian menu, that shows, hides divs on click. What I can't seem to figure out is how to load a swf into a div that sits on the page. Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#divId").html(swfHtmlString);
```

Comment: Wow, it's that simple? So, no embedding of swfobject or any of that ? What if I want a different swf to load into the same div on clicking of a different menu link? Is there also a simple way to do that? Thanks so much btw!

Comment: I meant to ask about the jQuery .load function as well, that's what I keep finding in the blogs.

Comment: Well you still have to embed everything like you normally would but the string would be loaded into the html like that.